# Injecting repository for Entity Framework context in middleware?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, middleware

Im creating a inhouse microservice. I pass the domain username in the header to my service and I want to ensure that no matter what endpoint is called a corrisponding user entity exists no matter what username is passed.
So I added a middleware that first of all ensures that Username is present in the header and checks if the user entity exists and if it doesnt it creates it.

However this gives me problems when I call the service multithreaded: 
when I send multiple request to the service the service throws a InvalidOperation exception with "Additional information: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open."

This the exception dump:

> {System.InvalidOperationException: The connection was not closed. The
>   connection's current state is connecting.    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosedConnecting.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(Boolean
>   buffer)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](Func`2
>   operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded, TState state)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_ShapedQuery>d__3`1.MoveNext()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_Include>d__30`1.MoveNext()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_Include>d__30`1.MoveNext()
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source)    at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext )    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c

This my context and repository registration:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        try
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

            var connectionString = Startup.Configuration["connectionStrings:whiteApplicationsDbConnectionString"];
            services.AddDbContext<WhiteApplicationContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(connectionString),ServiceLifetime.Scoped);

            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddScoped<IWhiteApplicationsRepository, WhiteApplicationsRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IWhiteUserRepository, WhiteUserRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IGroupRepository, GroupRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IDiskUtils, DiskUtils>();
            ConfigureAutoMapper();





        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
```

This is how I register the middleware:

```
app.UseMiddleware<ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationMiddleware>();
```

This is my middleware implementation:

```
public class ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationMiddleware
{
    private readonly IWhiteUserRepository _repository;
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next,IWhiteUserRepository _repository)
    {
        this.next = next;
        this._repository = _repository;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (!httpContext.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Username"))
        {
            await ReturnBadRequest(httpContext, "Username");
        }

        if (!httpContext.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Fullname"))
            await ReturnBadRequest(httpContext, "Fullname");


        if (!httpContext.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("MachineName"))
            await ReturnBadRequest(httpContext, "MachineName");


        var userName = httpContext.Request.Headers["Username"];
        var fullName = httpContext.Request.Headers["Fullname"];



        var user = _repository.GetUser(userName); //Exception is thrown here
        if (user == null)
            _repository.CreateUser(new DTOs.WhiteLogin { FullName = fullName, UserName = userName });






        await next.Invoke(httpContext);
    }

    private static async Task ReturnBadRequest(HttpContext httpContext, string missingValue)
    {
        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 400;
        await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync($"{missingValue} missing");
        return;
    }



}
```

The exception is thrown on this line:

```
 var user = _repository.GetUser(userName);
```

This is part of my User repository implementation:

```
public class WhiteUserRepository : IWhiteUserRepository, IDisposable
{
    private WhiteApplicationContext ctx;

    public WhiteUserRepository(WhiteApplicationContext _ctx)
    {
        this.ctx = _ctx;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ctx.Dispose();
    }


    public WhiteUser GetUser(string username)
    {
        var user = ctx.WhiteUsers.Include(x => x.UserGroupWhiteUsers).Include(x => x.UserMachineConnections).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username == username);




        return user;
    }

    public WhiteUser CreateUser(WhiteLogin whiteLogin)
    {
        var whiteUser = new WhiteUser { Username = whiteLogin.UserName, FullName = whiteLogin.FullName };

        ctx.WhiteUsers.Add(whiteUser);



        return whiteUser;
    }
```

If I remove the three lines accessing the database then everything works. 
My user repository is added as scoped and I have multiple active resultsets on the sql connection string, but it still doesnt work.
I havent found anything else that could explain this behavior..

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: InvalidOperationException. 
I've added all information to question.

Comment: Can you please show repository code?

Comment: @Manishkumarchoudhary, it has quite a few methods. I've added part of it. The part contains all methods called and ctor and Dispose

Comment: The problem is very probably in your implementation of IWhiteUserRepository and the way it access DB context. For more detailed answer you should provide more details about GetUser method.

Comment: @Zapo, I updated the question 5 mins ago with part of the implementation for IWhiteUserRepository. It contains the method in question, do you need any more info?

Comment: The problem I see is that you are getting context via injection and therefore there is a big probability, that you are mixing lifetimes of the repository and context.

Entity famework context cannot run in multiple threads simultaneously and also should handle no more that 1 web request. The context should be resolved on calling (e.g. via ServiceLocator or directly).

Comment: Ah, ok! I had something like that in mind. But my understanding of the architecture is that each request is piped through the middleware synchronously. I mean my MVC controller will not see the request until this middleware passes it on, and also a parallell request wont get the same instance of my Dbcontext, right? 
I will try instantiating a my concreate implementation of UserRepo to see if that helps...

Comment: Please show your context registration in `Startup.cs` as well.

Comment: @steamrolla, I've added the configureservices implementation and the call to add the custom middleware.